# In the Attack of the Clones poster made by Drew Struzan, why is Count Dooku/Darth Tyranus not included in the poster?

Tags: star-wars, posters, attack-of-the-clones

Since he is the main antagonist of the film he should be in the poster. The only antagonist in the poster is Jango Fett, the secondary antagonist of the film.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

He's definitely the bad guy — but even if it's a great character (played by a great actor), don't forget that:

1. He doesn't get too much screen time.
2. There's an important plot twist revealing his "dark" nature.

So, basically, they didn't want to spoil the movie ;-)

Fett, on the contrary, is far more known and recognizable.

Comment: But my point is what about those who already watch attack of the clones. Since they already know that dooku is the main antagonist ,they are expecting to include dooku in the poster.

Comment: Movie posters are generally made for the purposes of advertisement - to get people who haven't seen the movie to go see it, or to announce it even before it has been released.  Therefore spoilers are a concern.  After people have seen the movie is too late - the poster has already been made.

Comment: But what about Darth maul in the poster of episode 1 made by drew struzan,darth maul is the main villain of the phantom menace. Yet, darth maul is still included in the poster.